# Module '"@nestjs/config"' has no exported member 'ConfigModule'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, backend, config

I'm using NestJS,I installed @nestjs/config module using the command :

```
npm i --save @nestjs/config
```

I got this error :  **Module '"@nestjs/config"' has no exported member 'ConfigModule'**

this is my code in app.module file :

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { BookmarkModule } from './bookmark/bookmark.module';
import { PrismaModule } from './prisma/prisma.module';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule, AuthModule, UserModule, BookmarkModule, PrismaModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

PS : Node version : 17.6.0 / OS : Manjaro Linux

Comment: did you got that error when running `npm run build` or what?

Comment: I answered the quetion, you can check my answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was resolved by executing this command :

```
npm uninstall @nestjs/config && npm install @nestjs/config
```

Comment: time saving, thanks

Comment: worked on fedora 39 workstation Linux

Answer (score 3):

If the problem persist after applying [@Wahéb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14815045/wah%C3%A9b) answer, try:

- **on Windows**: `Shift + Ctrl + p` -> Restart TS server
- **on Mac**: `Cmd + Shift + p` -> Restart TS server

After this, you should have `ConfigModule` imported correctly.

Answer (score 1):

When installing ConfigModule, to make it detected, one should first stop the server, then install with "npm i --save @nestjs/config"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by deleting *node_modules* folder and reinstalling everything

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem beacue i use this npm command: npm i nestjs/config, but, the correct command is npm i @nestjs/config, if you uninstall and install again the package the problem will be resolved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).